# Python -- 3 dices game question by using while loop

Tags: python

I am a new learner on Python, I created a game to roll 3 dices randomly. I want to know how to go back to the "play" under "else". Please check my screenshot

```
import random
game = False
game1 = False
def roll():
    money = 0
    while game == False :
            money += 1   
            key = input("Please hit 'y' to roll the 3 dicks: ")
            if key == "y":
                 roll1 = random.randint(0,10)
                 roll2 = random.randint(0,10)
                 roll3 = random.randint(0,10)
                 print("Roll 1,2,3 are: ", roll1, roll2, roll3)
            else:
                print("Invalid input, try again")
                return roll()
            if roll1 == roll2 == roll3:
                money +=1
                print("You Win!")
                print("Your award is ", money)
                game == False
            else:
                play = input("Loss, try again? y or n? ")
                if play == "y":
                   money -= 1
                   game == False
                elif play == "n":
                     break
                else:
                   ??????????????????????
```

roll()
[image]

Comment: simple answer: create another `while` loop

Comment: how to add a while loop?

Comment: you've already added a while loop in the code above, haven't you?

Comment: Yes, after I added a while loop under the "else", I got an error when I input "y".

Answer (score 0):

You can just put it inside a while loop there:

```
else:
   while True: # you can 
      play = input("Loss, try again? y or n? ")
      if play == "y":
         money -= 1
         game == False
      elif play == "n":
         break
      else:
         pass
```

Comment: I got an error. What is "pass"? and why you put true inside ( )?

Comment: `pass` is like a placeholder; you don't have to put any code there. Please show me your error.

Comment: NameError: name 'true' is not defined. Did you mean: 'True'?

Comment: If you don't know what `pass` does, you should spend time going over Python fundamentals; that's the real problem, you need to learn about statements and loops and how they work together.

Comment: but the problem is system throwed an error, it doesn't know what is 'true'

Comment: I just fixed it. You should've used `True`